# Приложение вылетает при запуске

Tags: android, c++, исключения, cocos2d

Приложение написано на C++ под Android. Используется Cocos2d, Live2D.
Режим отладки — вылетает исключение.

```
DalvikVM[localhost:8600]    
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2264    
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2390 
    ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 151    
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1321  
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 110    
    Looper.loop() line: 193 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5292    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 515  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 824  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 640 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)    
Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running)
```

Режим релиза: приложение работает стабильно.

Comment: А в отладчике запускать пробовали?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Запускал как через отладчик, так и через обычный запуск. В любом случае, приложение вылетает. Хотя, настройки одни одни и те же, различие лишь в режиме:

`python ${ProjDirPath}/build_native.py -b release`

для релиза.

`python ${ProjDirPath}/build_native.py -b debug`

для дебага.

Также, вот Application.mk:

`APP_STL := c++_static

APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCC_ENABLE_CHIPMUNK_INTEGRATION=1 -std=c++11 -fsigned-char
APP_LDFLAGS := -latomic


ifeq ($(NDK_DEBUG),1)
  APP_CPPFLAGS += -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1
  APP_OPTIM := debug
else
  APP_CPPFLAGS += -DNDEBUG
  APP_OPTIM := release
endif`

Comment: Не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа в комментарии, [отредактируйте ваш вопрос вместо этого](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/467839/edit). Попробуйте [создать минимальный самодостаточный пример кода, который показывает проблему](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), иначе не хватает деталей, чтобы краткий ответ дать.